# Using ReactJS components properties in HTML attributes

Tags: reactjs

I am starting with React and there is something that I can't figure out. How can use a property to be the value of an html attribute?

See this code

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" value="{this.props.value}" />;
  }
});
```

I wanted to use the property `value` to be shown in the input but `{this.props.value}` is shown instead.

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks, they are making it a string:

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.props.value} />;
  }
});
```